# How to call Q function in a synchronous way

Tags: javascript, node.js, synchronization

I have a function:

```
const Q = require('q');
const timers = require('timers');

function _testQ() {
    const deferred = Q.defer();
    console.log('test timer event 1s.');
    let t = timers.setInterval(() => {
        console.log('Timer event!');
        timers.clearInterval(t);
        deferred.resolve(true);
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}
let out = _testQ().then((n) => {
    console.log('Debug1 n:', n);
});
console.log('Debug2 ', out);
```

How to call it in a syncronios manner.

I get output like this:

```
test timer event 1s.
Debug2  { state: 'pending' }
Timer event!
Debug1 n: true
```

I need it to print like this:

```
test timer event 1 s.
Timer event!
Debug1 n: true
Debug2 {state: 'pending'}
```

Comment: Try mocking it, and use the dummy object instead of the actual for test purpose, or else `stub` the `then` function.

Comment: If you need sync all, you may need `co` with `yield` or `async` with `await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well if you want Debug2 to be executed after Debug1 you need an additional .then block

```
let out = _testQ()
    .then((n) => {
        console.log('Debug1 n:', n);
    })
    .then(() => {
       console.log('Debug2 ');
    });
```

Comment: I have a very complex logic in my application so this is not an option. In this question, it is just an example. I am trying to do this with async and await.

Comment: thats not clear from your question whatsoever. also async/await is basically just syntactic sugar for promise handling. so afaik everything you can do with async/await you can also do by "old" promise chaining

Comment: Thx @Nicolas I did changes as you have suggested. Your solution is easier to implement then async/await.